# Pull data from PHP array based on a given infromation

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to pull `ImageUrl`'s, *Lat* and *Long* from a php array where I provide the HotelCode: `$hotelCode`

My XML file looks like the code below:

```
<Hotels>
    <Hotel>
        <HotelCode>Code<HotelCode>
        <Latitude>Lat</Latitude>
        <Longitude>Long</Longitude>
        <HotelImages>
            <ImageURL>file.jpg</ImageURL>
            <ImageURL>file2.jpg</ImageURL>
            ....
        </HotelImages>
    </Hotel>
    ....
</Hotels>
```

My PHP code is :

```
$xmlstring = file_get_contents($xmlurl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$hotels = json_decode($json,TRUE);

print_r($hotels) is:

Array ( 
   [Hotel] => Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
             [HotelCode] => ES002A 
             [comment] => Array ( 
                  [0] => Array ( ) ) 
             [Latitude] => 37.396792 
             [Longitude] => -5.992054 
             [HotelImages] => Array ( 
                 [ImageURL] => Array ( 
                     [0] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/ES002A/9405329_0x0.jpg 
                     [1] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/ES002A/9405330_0x0.jpg 
                     [2] => http://image.metglobal.com/hotelimages/ES002A/9405331_0x0.jpg 
                 ) 
            ) 
        ) 

print_r($hotelCodes) is

Array ( [0] => ESG56G [1] => ES0Z10 )
```

I have tried some diferent methods but none of them worked.

Comment: When it's xml you could use `xpath` instead of JSON. `Xpath` is more powerful for selecting data.

Comment: @Mouser i have tried with xpath but issloading very slow up to 1 min

Comment: How big is that xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off you have an error in your xml.

```
<HotelCode>Code<HotelCode>
```

Should be:

```
<HotelCode>Code</HotelCode>
```

After that you can get the images with:

```
$hotels['Hotel']['HotelImages']['ImageURL'][0];
```

and

```
$hotels['Hotel']['HotelImages']['ImageURL'][0];
```

And the lat long respectivly:

```
$hotels['Hotel']['Latitude'];

$hotels['Hotel']['Longitude'];
```

You can loop around the [Hotel] array with a foreach and check if the [HotelCode] element is equal to the one you provided and return the lat and long properties after that.

```
    foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
    if($hotel['HotelCode'] == 'YourCode'){
        echo $hotel['Latitude'];
        echo $hotel['Longtitude'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know, but how can i pull the imageURL where i provide the HotelCode?

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_keys`

```
$hotelCodes = array_keys($hotels, "HotelCode");
```

This will return all values with key "HotelCode". Then you can loop the array with these values.

```
foreach ($hotelCodes as $code)
{
     $iUrls = $hotels[$code]['HotelImages']['ImageURL'];
     foreach ($iUrls as $iUrl)
     {
         echo $iUrl;
     }
     echo $hotels[$code]['Latitude'];
     echo $hotels[$code]['Longitude'];
}
```